# Run mutliple integration tests in Flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, flutter-test

I have two integrations test files: login_test.dart and homepage_test.dart (each including single test case with  1 testWidgets method)

I'm using command line to run both tests:

```
flutter test integration_test/
```

But the problem is when the test has run and passed login_test . it completely reinstalled my app so second test will fail because have no login credentials (stuck at login screen -> failed)

Any idea how I can solve this ?

Appreciate your helps.

login_test.dart

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end to end tests', () {
    testWidgets('test login', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      app.main();

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      final Finder textFieldFinder = find.byType(TextFormField);
      expect(textFieldFinder, findsNWidgets(2));
      final userName = textFieldFinder.first;
      final password = textFieldFinder.last;

      await tester.enterText(userName, 'myusername');
      await tester.enterText(password, 'mypassword');

      expect(find.text('Login'), findsOneWidget);

      await tester.tap(find.text('Login'));

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();

      expect(find.byKey(Key('createTicketBtn')), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

homepage_test.dart

```
void main() {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('end to end tests', () {
    testWidgets('test homepage', (tester) async {
      app.main();

      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      expect(find.byKey(Key('createTicketBtn')), findsOneWidget);
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://pub.dev/packages/faster_driver) package to scan a folder inside the integration_test directory for files named like `*_test.dart`. This will produce a file with a new main importing all test files, so you can just run this new generated file.

You can also create manually a file like this and launch it:

```
import homepage_test.dart as homepage;
import login_test.dart as login;

void main() {
  homepage.main();
  login.main();
}
```

In any case, each test will start from the beginning so you need to login each time. The app will not lose its data though, unless you reset its state in the tearDown.